# F# SQLProvider error FS0039: type "dataContext" does not define a field, constructor or member "test". in demo

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

demo is here https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/mysql.html

```
type sql = SqlDataProvider<
                dbVendor,
                connString,
                ResolutionPath = resPath,
                IndividualsAmount = indivAmount,
                UseOptionTypes = useOptTypes,
                Owner = "HR"
            >
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()

let employees = 
    ctx.Hr.Employees 
    |> Seq.map (fun e -> e.ColumnValues |> Seq.toList)
    |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Since this is a type provider, I think you need a valid HR database at compile-time. Do you have such a database? If so, what does its schema look like?

Comment: There‘s no `test` in your code. Please provide the code that generates the error, including its dependencies (i.e. a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))